# Angular: Can I attach an Observable to a variable?

Tags: angular

This doesn't seem to work, yet there are no errors:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'geofinder',
  template: '<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="cityName" />'
})

export class GeoFinderComponent implements OnInit {

    cityName;

    ngOnInit() {
    let cityNameChange = Observable.from(this.cityName);
    cityNameChange.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    }

}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to attach an Observable to the variable which triggers when its value changes. I'd also be happy if I could bind the Observable to the keyup event of the input field, but it also refuses to work.

Comment: Instead of model update you can use event based observable on input field ?

Comment: Here is a snippet of a tutorial I tried to follow. However it doesn't work for some reason. It probably only worked in Angular 2 beta. https://pastebin.com/Cp0ZkTJA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *You could...*

Use a setter and just add your handling there

```
_cityName;

get cityName() {
  return this._cityName;
}

set cityName(name) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

### *You could...*

Split up the `[(ngModel)]` so you could call your callback with the `(ngModelChange)` hook

```
'<input [ngModel]="cityName" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>'

cityName;

onChange(newCity) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

### *You could...*

Use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) if you want an Observable. You can hook to the `valueChanges` (which is an `Observable`) of the `FormControl` or `FormGroup`

```
formControl = new FormControl()

formControl.valueChanges().debounceTime(..).filter(..)
```

If you've never used reactive forms before, you should go through the guide I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks, this one works too, but an Observable would be better and more elegant. For instance I'd like to use debounce and filtering.

Comment: Use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

Comment: Ah yes, this third one is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!